# Using Jenkins to upolad images to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-ecr

I'm using Jenkins to upload our docker images to AWS with Kaniko, but everytime a try something the log of Jenkins is the same message error of authorization. I already gave the total permissions to the IAM user and declared the credentials on the fields to do so. The part of the code is:

```
steps {
                checkout scm
                sh """
                echo "{\\\"auths\\\":{\\\"${CI_REGISTRY}\\\":{\\\"auth\\\":\\\"\$(printf "%s:%s" "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}" "${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" | base64 | tr -d '\\n')\\\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
                cat /kaniko/.docker/config.json
                export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"
                export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
                /kaniko/executor \
                    --context=dir://./ \
                    --custom-platform=linux/amd64 \
                    --dockerfile=Dockerfile \
                    --snapshotMode=redo \
                    --use-new-run \
                    --destination="${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_SERVICE}:${TAG_NAME}" \
                    --cache=true \
                    --verbosity=debug \
                    --cache-run-layers
                """
            }
```

The error log on Jenkis is:

```
Copying file /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Orbcomm2_teste-jenkins-51/Dockerfile to /kaniko/Dockerfile 
error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: checking push permission for "731353370725.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ci-registry-aws/trackit-satellite:teste-jenkins-51": POST https://731353370725.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/ci-registry-aws/trackit-satellite/blobs/uploads/: unexpected status code 401 Unauthorized: Not Authorized

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (End Message)
Stage "End Message" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've tried to login on docker on command lines, but the error of authorization was the same.
Somabody have a clue?

It was supposed that this would build images fine, so i could apply to the other repos